# json filtering with ignoring some objects

Tags: json, jq

I need to extract with jq filter following output:

`id:1022 mname:P1 target:host.domain.com pname:P1A xnode:1`

All objects having pname beginning with `#` in `xstart` sections should be ignored from processig.

the input json is:

```
{
  "id": 1022,
  "mname": "P1",
  "attrib": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "log",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": 622,
      "name": "target",
      "value": "host.domain.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 623,
      "name": "iddle",
      "value": "30"
    }
  ],
  "xstart": [
    {
      "id": 1021,
      "pname": "P1A",
      "attrib": [
        {
          "id": 530,
          "name": "xnode",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": 498,
          "name": "remote",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1022,
      "pname": "#P1C",
      "attrib": [
        {
          "id": 530,
          "name": "xnode",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": 498,
          "name": "remote",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: Please clarify the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '"id:" + (.id|tostring) + " mname:" + .mname 
       + " target:" + (.attrib[] | select(.name == "target").value) 
       + " pname:" + (.xstart[] | select(.pname | startswith("#") | not) as $x | $x.pname 
       + " xnode:" + ($x.attrib[] | select(.name=="xnode").value))' input.json
```

The output:

```
id:1022 mname:P1 target:host.domain.com pname:P1A xnode:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the requirements have mostly been specified implicitly, it's difficult to infer them, but the following probably comes close and in any case illustrates some useful techniques, such as the abstraction of the functionality embodied in the following definition of `kv`:

```
def kv: [to_entries[] | "\(.key):\(.value)" ] | join(" ");

.attrib |= map(select(.name == "target"))
| .xstart |= map( select(has("pname") and (.pname | startswith("#") | not)))
| {id, mname, target: "host.domain.com"}
  + (.xstart[]
     | .pname as $pname
     | .attrib[]
     | {pname: $pname} + {(.name): .value})
| kv
```

### Output

With the given input and the use of the `-r` command-line option, the output would be:

```
id:1022 mname:P1 target:host.domain.com pname:P1A xnode:1
id:1022 mname:P1 target:host.domain.com pname:P1A remote:1
```